# Refer to a macrolist which name depends on a variable

Tags: sql, sas

```
%let list_2=‘a’,’b’,’c’;
PROC SQL;  

CREATE TABLE test AS  

SELECT    
     Bin,  /*value is a*/  
     Rank, /*value is 2*/  
     CASE  
     WHEN Bin IN (&list_Rank.)   /*list_2=‘a’,’b’,’c’*/  
     THEN 1  
     ELSE 0  
     END     AS test   

FROM     Source  
;  
QUIT;
```

I am looking for a way to use the value of column Rank in the reference to the macrovariable list_2.

Comment: resolve(‘&list_’||compress(put(Rank,best.))) gives the textual content, but this does nog work in a macroreference...

Comment: I have a number of macrovariables named list_i, ranging from 1to 901. Which macrovariable I want to call depends on the value in column Rank. So instead of &list_Rank I am looking for a way to dynamically refer to the value of column Rank to botanische a reference to  list_2. Does this clarify the question?

Comment: You should look up the symget function. Not sure if it works in Proc sql though.

Comment: How did you get the lists into the macro variables? Did they come from a table? why not just join to the table instead?

Answer (score 4):

As @John commented, you can use SYMGET function to use data to look up the value of a macro variable during run-time.  I don't think you can use the IN operator for what you want, because it expects a list of character strings, while SYMGET will return a single string.  Below I took the quotes out of the &LIST_2 (just to make it easier to work with), and used FINDW to do the work of IN.  I think this is along the lines of what you're describing:

```
%let list_2=a,b,c;
%let list_3=d,e,f ;

data have ;
  input bin $1. rank ;
  cards ;
a 2
a 3
e 2
e 3
;
run ;

proc sql ;
  select
    bin
   ,rank
   ,case when findw(symget(cats("list_",rank))
                   ,bin
                   ) then 1
    else 0
    end as test
   ,symgetc(cats("list_",rank)) as symgetc /*debugging*/
   from have ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add another `CASE` statement.  Actually since it is SAS code you could eliminate the current CASE statement and just use the result of the IN operation which will be 0 (false) or 1 (true).

```
%let list_1='a','b','c';
%let list_2='d','e','f';
%let nlists=2;

PROC SQL;  

CREATE TABLE test AS  
SELECT    
     Bin   /*value is a*/  
   , Rank  /*value is 2*/  
   , case
       when (rank=1) then bin in (&list_1)
       when (rank=2) then bin in (&list_2)
       else 0  
     end as test    
FROM Source  
;  
QUIT;
```

If you are running inside a macro you could use a `%do` loop to generate the `when` clauses.

```
%do i=1 %to &nlists ;
  when (rank=&i) then bin in (&&list_&i)
%end;
```

If you are not in a macro then create a macro to run the `%do` loop and call it at the appropriate place.